# How to know the size of the information sent through a socket (serialized object)

Tags: c#, arrays, serialization, server

I am implementing a client-server communication. I need to send a response to the client whose size may vary, because it contains a serialized array:

```
[Serializable]
public struct ServerResponse
{
    public ApplicationAction ApplicationAction { get; set; }
    public Product[] AssociatedProducts { get; set; }
}
```

What I am currently doing is serializing my instance of ServerResponse to XML using XmlSerializer (it wouldn't bother me at all to use another method my data doesn't need to be human-readable) and writing it on the socket stream like so:

```
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ServerResponse));
        NetworkStream networkStream = client.GetStream();
        if (networkStream.CanWrite)
        {
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(networkStream, response);
        }
```

My problem is that the client does not know the size of the data it needs to read. 
My guess is to first send the size of the data and then all the data, but to do that I need to know

> how can I get the actual size of a serialized object ?

Thanks

Comment: What method of serialization do you use, please specify. Do you use json format? Binary? XML? or other. Provide code you use to serialize this class.

Comment: I edited the question. I am using XML but I don't mind using another format since my data don't need to be human readable, maybe binary would be even more suitable.

Comment: I would suggest to serialize the `ServerResponse` to a local file (e.g., a temporary file) and then send that file to the client. Due to it's a local file, you know its size.

Comment: @dcg Using drive to store temporary data is a bad practice, if you dont need this data later. Always use memory for temporary data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Befor you will send any data you should serialize your Stream to the memory using `MemoryStream`. Then you can take its lenght and multiply by `sizeof(byte)`

Your code will look something like this:

```
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(JsonQuestion));
        NetworkStream networkStream = client.GetStream();
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(memoryStream, response);
        var length = memoryStream.Length * sizeof(byte);
        //Send size
        ...
        //Send data
        if (networkStream.CanWrite)
        {
            memoryStream.CopyTo(networkStream);
        }
```

Comment: What happens if the `ServerResponse` is large?

Comment: You would cache everything to memory before sending data. But you are still doing this, because if I'm not mistaken, all default serializers store all data in stream before they will be sent.

Comment: Ok, I was mistaken. MemoryStream will make additional strain on memory, since you would have to cache all data in bytes form before sending it. But you have no other (fast) option to know the exact lenght of data you will send. You could use only some kind of approximation, on how mutch additional data XmlTextWriter will add to final string if you dont need to know amount of data to the byte.

Comment: the other thing I was thinking about is to change the logic of the client and read the data as it comes, i.e. by chunks, and then you would forget about computing the size of what you are sending from the server.

Comment: You dont have to send it in chunks, look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26058594/how-to-get-all-data-from-networkstream