# How to read with NetworkStream to get full HTTP response (proxy)?

Tags: c#, http, tcp, header, networkstream

Currently I am building TCP proxy, which works by sending HTTP request it got from browser to website and then immideately reading response from it with this code:

```
byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
NetworkStream stream = tcpclient.GetStream();
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    int length;
    while ((length = tcpclient.Available) > 0)
    {
        length = (length > buff.Length) ? (buff.Length) : (length);
        stream.Read(buff, 0, length);
        ms.Write(buff, 0, length);
    }
    byte[] data = ms.ToArray();
}
```

But I have encountered problem:
If website sends response too slow *while()* is just skipped because code reached *while()* before any data arrived to proxy. *Thread.Sleep()* is obviously not a solution because I need to get data as soon as it arrives plus some websites can have huge delay.
I thought that I can bypass this problem by setting minimum data size to get, that way I could get HTTP response header and look for *Content-Size*, but I checked some responses and header size highly varies, so *Content-Size* property can be on 10th byte, or on 100th, or even more, but on the other hand there are HTTP responses that are smaller in size (header+body) than just headers of some responses. 
I could also use async receive for better structure, but I still need right data size to receive.

Now, questions:
1) **Should I find perfect byte amount to receive** to get all parts of header I need, but not to loose small responses or there is another way to reliably get whole HTTP response, no matter how big or small is it?
2) Question more related to HTTP structure - I saw response, which type was *chunked*. As far as I understand, one big response splitted to parts, which then sent to client. However I am not sure how it works - is to one sent request many *chunked* responses sent? Or after every *chunked* response client makes another request to server to sent him next *chunked* response? Basically what I ask is: **Is it possible that for one HTTP request from browser more than one response from website will be sent?**
3) **I can even use HttpListener instead of TCPlistener for getting requests and responses**, it will be much easier. But I saw a topic where HttpListener was used for proxy and most popular answer was that you should not use HttpListener because it has far too much problems so it was recommended to use TCPlistener for proxy. Is that right? Topic is really old though, maybe something changed in .NET.

I've read this topic: [How to get all data from NetworkStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26058594/how-to-get-all-data-from-networkstream), however all answers rely on same thing - read while data is available, which does not work for me as I stated previously.

Comment: You should implement  as a do loop with the while at the end of the loop.  See msdn : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26058594/how-to-get-all-data-from-networkstream

Comment: Thanks, that worked for my first question. Do you have any knowledge aboutmy second question? For some reason I can't find any confirmed information about request-response topic.

Comment: Http 1.0 is stream mode and Http 1.1 is chunk mode.  I've never got 1.1 to work with Net Library and a lot of people have same issue.  Chunk mode the client has to send a next chunk message after receiving each chunk otherwise a timeout will occur.  I've never found a way to send next chunk message.  So usually in my initial request I add the version 1.0 header which will force server into stream mode.